# Pathing issues with using ./ in a Rakefile on Windows

Tags: javascript, ruby, windows, bash, rake

I have the following Rakefile...

```
namespace :dev do
    desc "Execute my-bash-script."
    task :done do
        sh "./bin/my-bash-script.sh" # <-- Error on this line
    end 
end
```

Which I execute successfully on my Mac with `rake dev:done`

When I run the command on my Windows machine however, I receive a `Command failed with status (127)` error on the `sh "./bin/my-bash-script.sh"` line.

I figured there was a pathing issue with using `./` so I tried replacing `./` in the Rakefile with `#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}` but am still receiving the same error.

**What am I doing incorrectly?**

Comment: No, still receiving the same error :(

Comment: can you run you `sh` script outside the ruby script? (e.g. from the command line)

Comment: Yes. The script is executable from outside the Rakefile

Answer (score 0):

Under windows, passing forward slashes in a path to the shell does not work.
You need to replace all '/' with '\' in the command string.